# How to create BiqQuery view from SQL source in a file (Windows command line)

Tags: view, google-bigquery

I created a number of BigQuery views and all works well. I need to move the SQL source for the queries into my source control and manage changes from there. Is there a way to create/update a view from the command line using the source from a file? The bq mk command seems to only allow the SQL code to be inline on the command line --view keyword. Some of my views are quite lengthy and I'm sure there are characters that would need to be escaped - which I obviously don't want to get into. I'm running on Windows. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't answer your immediate question, but consider signing up for the [preview of the new BigQuery UI](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf6hyfvoWZ8eUbbKWq9fzVfj7ljVyl2SdhtWH038Xrx2eHVrw/viewform). It will also give you early access to DDL statements like CREATE VIEW.

Comment: @Elliot-brossard - will this give me the ability to create/update a view by using the command line to point to a file from that contains the DDL?  I'm really surprised that this is turning out to be so difficult. Thanks!

Comment: It would mean that you can use `bq query` and pipe a `CREATE VIEW` statement to it.

Comment: And that can be done on windows?  I'm no windows expert but I've had trouble in the past with special characters (eg. newlines) when I try to pipe/redirect input.  

The syntax would be something like this?
But if it works, that would be great

Comment: Sorry about botching that last post - here is what I meant to say:

And that can be done on windows?  I'm no windows expert but I've had trouble in the past with special characters (eg. newlines) when I try to pipe/redirect input.  

What would the syntax look like on windows on Windows (assuming I pipe the SQL statements)?

I submitted my request to join the alpha - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the `flagfile` parameter:

`bq mk --help`:

> --flagfile: Insert flag definitions from the given file into the command line.

`bq mk --view --flagfile=<path_to_to_your_file> dataset.newview`

Comment: Thanks @graham-polley for the quick response - and it gets me closer my objective. But it only works as long as there are no new line characters. When I input a file with newline characters (some of my queries are quite long) I get a parsing error. I tried changing to linux-style new lines but that didn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: Also finding the error `Too many positional args, still have ...` which I assume is from newline characters.

Answer (score 3):

Let us assume that file `MyQuery.sql` contains view definition.

Create a Script file `script.sh` with below contents

```
query=`cat MyQuery.sql`    
bq mk --use_legacy_sql=false --view "$query"  dataset.myview
```

Run using command `sh script.sh`

This worked for me in Shell..!! You can make necessary changes for Windows..!!

Comment: I was able to skip the shell variable and just do

`bq mk --use_legacy_sql=false --view "\`cat my_view.sql\`" dataset.myview`

right from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use bq query command, ex:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false < ${file}
```